# Как писать: организованно прошел экзамен

Tags: синтаксис

Как писать: организованно прошел экзамен

Answer (score 3):

Так и писать: организованно прошел экзамен

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так  экзамен прошел организованно. А что имелось в виду в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

я почему-то подумала, что здесь вопрос в количестве Н. Тогда правильно так, как Вы написали.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос связан с правописание согласной **Н**, то здесь пишутся две НН.  Если Вы хотите знать, как лучше всего оформить это предложение, то, по мне, "Экзамен прошёл организованно" - самый благозвучный и правильный (не думаю, что найдутся сторонники другого тезиса) вариант.